# How to fix the problem with wget google docs redirect

Tags: bash, wget, google-docs

Need your help, i faced with a problem and i can't use my documents from google docs. In the logs that I listed one file downloaded normally like xlsx and another, after redirect, sending me file in another format that i can't use. I'm using wget to download and i think that there are some problems with redirect, because when i try to download it via my browser it works fine. Do you have any suggestons?

```
--2020-11-19 00:52:39--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSq821D8kmbYBKoyf2Ozv5RBBjJFWMXw7LrUIPPmNmTF9in1Csdp2fG7SPF79o9SwJnCYQTYAdRlz6N/pub?output=xlsx&ndplr=1
Resolving docs.google.com (docs.google.com)... 173.194.73.194
Connecting to docs.google.com (docs.google.com)|173.194.73.194|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com/pub/l5l039s6ni5uumqbsj9o11lmdc/8mqrbr7h1trmomb4rrg5q3us94/1605736355000/109767831902272150959/*/e@2PACX-1vSq821D8kmbYBKoyf2Ozv5RBBjJFWMXw7LrUIPPmNmTF9in1Csdp2fG7SPF79o9SwJnCYQTYAdRlz6N?output=xlsx&ndplr=1 [following]
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
--2020-11-19 00:52:40--  https://doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com/pub/l5l039s6ni5uumqbsj9o11lmdc/8mqrbr7h1trmomb4rrg5q3us94/1605736355000/109767831902272150959/*/e@2PACX-1vSq821D8kmbYBKoyf2Ozv5RBBjJFWMXw7LrUIPPmNmTF9in1Csdp2fG7SPF79o9SwJnCYQTYAdRlz6N?output=xlsx&ndplr=1
Resolving doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com (doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com)... 64.233.162.132
Connecting to doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com (doc-0s-b4-sheets.googleusercontent.com)|64.233.162.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet]
Saving to: ‘/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFilesFromMail/FoxgamerPrices/ArozziGlasses.xlsx’

/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFiles     [ <=>                                                                                                                      ]   8,37K  --.-KB/s    in 0,006s  

2020-11-19 00:52:40 (1,29 MB/s) - ‘/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFilesFromMail/FoxgamerPrices/ArozziGlasses.xlsx’ saved [8575]

--2020-11-19 00:52:40--  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output=xlsx&ndplr=1
Resolving docs.google.com (docs.google.com)... 173.194.73.194
Connecting to docs.google.com (docs.google.com)|173.194.73.194|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output%3Dxlsx%26ndplr%3D1&followup=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output%3Dxlsx%26ndplr%3D1&ltmpl=sheets [following]
--2020-11-19 00:52:40--  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output%3Dxlsx%26ndplr%3D1&followup=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output%3Dxlsx%26ndplr%3D1&ltmpl=sheets
Resolving accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)... 108.177.14.84
Connecting to accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)|108.177.14.84|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFilesFromMail/FoxgamerPrices/AKRacingChairs.xlsx’

/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFiles     [ <=>                                                                                                                      ]  62,03K  --.-KB/s    in 0,04s   

2020-11-19 00:52:41 (1,38 MB/s) - ‘/Users/a.trofimenko/Documents/ToolsForShop/SavedFilesFromMail/FoxgamerPrices/AKRacingChairs.xlsx’ saved [63521]
```

Comment: Please share the command you are trying to use

Comment: @Alessandro it's simply 
wget "https://$VALUE" --output-document="$PWD/FoxgamerPrices/$KEY.xlsx"
where value is like:
docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRTODOmG41UHNiEQ37zx_j4S7CIn9YlUPstsR6mBcwaTMP72Tpeue29lV-dxdvurroPQCgxqAS6_Wsa/pub?output=xlsx&ndplr=1

Comment: The second link you are trying to access is not public: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQoEw0Bm6CxxsGzlSZCCiB7Cw5kAsCYPerddQGOGy1fvIE1WnklabWIAxPeCO0UO76Jn3m5PbKj56t9/pub?output=xlsx&ndplr=1. You won't be able to download without proper authentication.

Comment: @Alessandro yes, thanks, i third about that, but it was working, but now i changed password on gmail account and i think problem is this. But some of files downloaded successfully, and i don't understand why.

Comment: In order to be able to download a file without authorization it must be public. You can download it through your browser because you are logged in.  Could you check if the rest of the files that downloaded successfully are shared publically? Also are these files supposed to be public or private? Thanks ! :D